# Laravel 360Dialog {"meta": {"success": false, "http_code": 400, "developer_message": "Invalid payload ()", "error": ""}}

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy llamado a la API de 360Dialog y no me resulta pasarle $minombre al campo TO y $minumero al Parameters Text como parametros al Payload. Parece que el **Heredoc <<<'PAYLOAD'** no me permite hacerlo o yo lo estoy haciendo mal.

```
$minombre = "Eduardo Tapia";
$minumero = "56996436710";
        
// comienzo llamado API 360Dialog

$url = "https://waba-sandbox.360dialog.io/v1/messages";

$payload = <<<'PAYLOAD'
{
    "to": $minumero,
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "namespace": "c8ae5f90_307a_ca4c_b8f6_d1e2a2573574",
        "language": {
            "policy": "deterministic",
            "code": "en"
        },
        "name": "first_welcome_messsage",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": $minombre
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
PAYLOAD;
```

¿Como hago para pasar los parametros variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

La razón por la que tus variables no se "expanden" es porque estás utilizando `Nowdoc`, puedes hacerlo con `Heredoc`. Para información detallada de `Nowdoc` y `Heredoc` visita [este sitio](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Sólo quita las comillas simples de `'PAYLOAD'` para convertir tu `Nowdoc` a `Heredoc`

```
$minombre = "Eduardo Tapia";
$minumero = "56996436710";
        
// comienzo llamado API 360Dialog

$url = "https://waba-sandbox.360dialog.io/v1/messages";

$payload = <<<PAYLOAD
{
    "to": $minumero,
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "namespace": "c8ae5f90_307a_ca4c_b8f6_d1e2a2573574",
        "language": {
            "policy": "deterministic",
            "code": "en"
        },
        "name": "first_welcome_messsage",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": $minombre
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
PAYLOAD;
```